# MySQL sort records by two alternating static values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table full of data like so:

```
ID      datetime            ip_address      marker
289055  2016-11-17 17:54:51 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
289037  2016-11-17 17:54:51 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289057  2016-11-17 17:58:56 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289123  2016-11-17 17:59:18 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
289184  2016-11-17 18:05:55 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
289125  2016-11-17 18:05:55 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289186  2016-11-17 18:12:22 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289292  2016-11-17 18:18:44 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
```

I'm trying to sort the data by two values ("Start", "End") but "banded". What I mean by this is as follows:

```
ID      datetime            ip_address      marker
289037  2016-11-17 17:54:51 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289055  2016-11-17 17:54:51 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
289057  2016-11-17 17:58:56 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289123  2016-11-17 17:59:18 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
289125  2016-11-17 18:05:55 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289184  2016-11-17 18:05:55 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
289186  2016-11-17 18:12:22 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Start
289292  2016-11-17 18:18:44 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  End
```

Notice how the `marker` column pivots between Start and End (start always being first and End always being last). I believe what I want to accomplish is possible but I'm not getting how to manipulate this data into what I want. I've tried a few different queries grouping or ordering by various columns however it always ends up either like the first table, or all records with "Start" as the `marker` grouped together, followed by "End".

Comment: Why can't you use `ORDER BY datetime, marker desc`? It will produce desired result unless I am missing something (you did not explain how start-end pairs are connected).

Comment: The `ID` column, is it auto increase? Does rows with `marker=Start` will always have smaller `ID` than `marker=End`?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8+, this is easy:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by marker order by datetime),
         marker desc
```

This is much more challenging in earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: 10 guesses which version of MySQL I’m *not* running!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an addition into your `SELECT...` to use in your ordering. For example:

```
SELECT ID,datetime,ip_address,marker,
CASE WHEN marker='Start' THEN 1 WHEN marker='End' THEN 2 END AS 'mcheck'
FROM table
ORDER BY datetime,ipaddress,mcheck;
```